# React Router - TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Stumbled upon this issue working with React. I can't seem to find a solution. The stack trace doesn't help much because the script is bundled with webpack.

Here's what I got from the console

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
Warning: Only functions or strings can be mounted as React components.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
```

Encountered when trying to render this App component

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import { TableRequest, TableEngineer } from './tables.jsx'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
export class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
                <Route path="/" component={Index}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
                    <Route path="indeks-permohonan" component={TableRequest} />
                    <Route path="indeks-work-order" component={TableEngineer} />
                    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
            )
    }
}
```

Package list

```
├── babel-core@5.8.25
├── babel-loader@5.3.2
├── file-loader@0.8.4
├── history@1.10.1
├── lodash@3.10.1
├── path@0.12.7
├── react@0.13.3
├── react-bootstrap@0.25.2
├── react-hot-loader@1.3.0
├── react-router@1.0.0-rc1
├── react-router-bootstrap@0.19.0
├── reactable@0.11.4
├── webpack@1.12.2
└── webpack-dev-server@1.11.0
```

Comment: You're not importing the `NotFound` component.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the complete script, should have added a note saying that these components are in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means `String` is `undefined` and code is calling `toUpperCase()` on such string which is not defined. You have to figure out where that piece of code is in your files. You can simply add a undefined check before calling `toUpperCase()` on such string.

Comment: It points to the `react` library. But in my case it only happens when I try to render the `Router` and `Route` components from another library which is `react-router`.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `react-router` to v1.0. The error happens when you use v0.13.

npm installs that version because there is no stable 1.0 release yet. You have to manually add `^1.0.0-rc1` to your package.json.

Comment: Yes I did use the `1.0.0-rc1` version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `Index`, `Home` and `NotFound` components.

Comment: Sorry, I left them out, I should have written that they're in the same file.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure all of your components are exported?  I see this sometimes if I forget to do `module.exports = Component;`